# Insert long strings into SQL

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to insert long strings into SQL Server like:

```
"    [$('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'}), ['type:Input']];  "
```

without having to break it into dozens of pieces?

Comment: What do you mean by **without having to break it into dozens of pieces**?

Answer (score 1):

Silly question, and here is the silly answer:

```
declare @longstring varchar(max)
set @longstring = '[$('''').attr({''class'':''inp''}), [''type:Input'']];'
```

Comment: your answer is what I was asking about avoiding.